# How to calculate equilibria of the sum of "similar" Hamiltonians

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, equilibrium

Determining equilibria of a Hamiltonian system is equivalent to finding the zeroes of a function, so in general it is a hard task- 
But what if we have some additional information on the Hamiltonians?
Let's consider a family Hamiltonians with a similar form:
\begin{equation}
H_i(p,q) = f(p,q,k_i)
\end{equation}
where the $k_i$ are some parameters. Let's also assume that we know the equilibrium points for each $H_i$.
I am trying to figure out if there is some tool to extract information about the equilibrium points of
\begin{equation}
H(p,q) = \sum_i H_i(p,q,k_i)
\end{equation} 
where the coordinates $(p,q)$ are the same for all the Hamiltonians.
I think there should be some correlation between the equilibria of the $H$ system and those of each $H_i$ but I cannot figure out if it's the case.

Comment: It's not clear in your formulation if the coordinates $(p,q)$ are the same for each of the $H_i$ or if they belong to different degrees of freedom. In the latter case, the subsystems belonging to different degrees of freedom would be non-interacting and the problem could be solved separately for each of the $H_i$.  If, instead, $(p,q)$ are common to each of the $H_i$, I fail to imagine an example of such a Hamiltonian.

Comment: The coordinates are the same, I'll edit the question for clarity.